# Проблемы с Eclipse. Could not find or load main class.

Tags: java, eclipse

Пару дней назад данный код работал, а сейчас начались проблемы. Код не менялся. но программа не запускается. Можно только объяснить глюками Еклипса.

Answer (score 6):

Пару дней назад отвечал на подобный вопрос:

1. Run -> Run Configurations...
2. Слева в разделе Java Applications (Applets) ищете или создаете свой проект. Ему можно задать имя, а также выбрать **Project:** т.е. ваш исходный проект в Java, **Main class:** куда вы должны указать имя вашего главного класса, в котором содержится функция `main`

Функция `main` должна выглядеть так:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //your code here
}
```

Comment: Человек пишет, что он ничего не трогал а все сломалось само.

Answer (score 2):

Правый клик в окне редактора нужного класса (с main) -> Run as... -> Java appilcation. Перезапускать можно через Ctrl+F11

Answer (score 0):

В моем проекте, подобная проблема была решена следующим способом:

1. `maven update`
2. `build all`

Answer (score 0):

Может кому нибудь поможет. 
Закрыл эклипс полностью. Папку с проектом ВЫГРЫЗ из воркспейса в другой каталог. Запустил эклипс снова. Он пометил проект который изчез другой иконкой. Нажимаем на неё и резрешаем её удалить либо сами удаляем. далее опять перезапускаем эклипс. добавляем папку рукамив обратно в воркспейс. и т.к. у меня был проект мавен я добавлял существующий проект мавен. Ну а если простой проект, то по почти такой же схеме Импорт-дженерал-экзистинг проджект- далее находите нужную папку и подгружаете свой проект в project или package explorer(это окна так называются для просмотра проектов). ВсЁ. У меня заработало.